# Deriving formula for curvature of a Curve.

Tags: differential-geometry

So I have this formula for a regular curve $\gamma (t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\kappa = \frac{\vert\vert \overset{\cdot\cdot}{\gamma}\times\overset{\cdot}{\gamma}\vert\vert}{\vert\vert \overset{\cdot}{\gamma}\vert\vert^3}$

The proof of which starts by stating:
Let $s$ be a unit speed parameter for $\gamma$. Then, by the chain rule,

$\overset{\cdot}{\gamma}=\frac{d\gamma}{dt}=\frac{d\gamma}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}$

What I don't understand is why can you reparametrize $\gamma$ without changing the function? Whenever reparametrization was shown before it was shown as $\overset{\sim}{\gamma}(s(t))=\gamma(t)$, where $s$ is usually the arc length and is a function of $t$. But here it seems like they've taken the function $\gamma(t)=\gamma(s(t))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametrization of a curve does not affect the shape of the curve, only the speed which the curve is traversed. That is, $\gamma(f(t))$ is the same curve for any continuous $f$, only the direction and speed at which the curve is being traced is changed. We normally choose the arc length parametrization, since it’s arguably the “simplest” speed, 1 unit per second.

Comment: But when a curve is reparametrized does the function change? Say a curve $\gamma$ with parameter $t$. Is a reparametrization just $\gamma(s(t))$ a composition of the original function with the new parameter?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but for an example let’s take $\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$,and $\gamma(t^2)=(\cos(t^2),\sin(t^2))$. You should recognize this as the unit circle. Now imagine varying $t$, from $0$ to $2$. $\gamma(t)$ traces out the unit circle from $0$ to $2$ radians, just past a quarter of the circle. However for the same range of $t$, $\gamma(t^2)$ traces out $0$ to $4$ radians, double the length traced by our first parametrization. Hopefully you can agree that if we let $t$ vary both of these will trace out the unit circle, only the speed is different.